# Why are "--slave" and "--no-restore" being used by commandArgs when I call my R file with Rscript

Tags: r, linux, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, rscript

I am running an R script using *Rscript* from the command line (linux) like this:

```
Rscript myscript.R inputfile1.csv inputfile.csv integerArg
```

My command args are structured like this

```
  cmd_args <- commandArgs() 
  infile1 <- cmd_args[1]
  infile2 <- cmd_args[2]
  intArg <- cmd_args[3]

  main_func<-function(infile1, infile2, intArg){
  print(infile1)
  print(infile2)
  print(intArg)
  }

  main_func(infile1, infile2, intArg)
```

This prints out

> [1] "/home/miniconda3/envs/bionano_python3.0/lib/R/bin/exec/R"
> [1] "--slave"
> [1] "--no-restore"

I guess I don't have to tell you that the script gives an error the first time it hits one of the input arguments.

I have also tried running the script like this and it gives the exact same output/error

`R --slave --no-restore --file=myscript.R --args inputfile1.csv inputfile.csv integerArg`

I'm confused because I am not setting these flags when I call Rscript so why are they appearing, and how can I make the commandArgs read only the designated input parameters? Any ideas on how to solve this issue? I can't seem to find any information about why this could be happening and I'm clearly just missing something. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That's just the way it is" with `Rscript`.

One fix: use `commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)`

Another fix: use `littler` (see [littler at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=littler) which prunes the arguments similar to `trailingOnly=TRUE` and leaves them in `argv[]

And another fix: use eg `docopt` which standardizes option process (see [docopt at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=docopt).

There are a bunch of examples combining `littler` and `docopt` in the [littler repo in inst/examples](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/tree/master/inst/examples). I have used a number of those daily for many years.  "Works for me" as they say.